# What is the difference between using 'AS' or not in SQL Server table name alias?

Tags: sql-server

I have seen table aliases written two ways and I am trying to find out if there is a performance difference or something. Is there a difference between the 2 statements below, and if so, what?

```
Select Id from tbl_Students S
```

and

```
Select Id from tbl_Students AS S
```

Comment: None, `AS` is a optional keyword. This is shown in the [Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) section of the documentation, where you'll note `AS` is in brackets (`[]`), which denotes the keyword is optional.

Comment: [Note that the AS keyword is completely optional and is usually kept for readability purposes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL))